# Any integral is equal to the integral of the indicator function of its graph

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The following seems intuitively true to me but I’m not sure if it is true in general, and if so how to prove it.

For any $T \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and function $f: T \to \mathbb{R}$, let $A = \{ \mathbf{x}~|~f(\mathbf{x}) > 0, \mathbf{x} \in T\}$ be where the function is positive and $B = T \setminus{A}$ where it is non-positive, and define the *graphs* on $A$ and $B$ to be the sets
$$ S_1 = \{(\mathbf{x}, y))~|~\mathbf{x} \in A, 0 < y < f(\mathbf{x})\} $$
and
$$ S_2 = \{(\mathbf{x}, y))~|~\mathbf{x} \in B, f(\mathbf{x}) < y \leq 0\} ,$$
respectively. Then we have that
$$ \int_{T} f(\mathbf{x})~d^n\mathbf{x} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} \mathbf{1}_{S_1}~d^{n+1}\mathbf{x} - \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} \mathbf{1}_{S_2}~d^{n+1}\mathbf{x} ,$$
provided the first integral exists.

Any ideas?

Comment: The graph has measure zero.

Comment: How about now @Paul

Comment: Any Ideas?  Fubini's theorem.  [Use FT to figure out the correct formulation; I think this isn't it.]

Comment: @GEdgar Do you know where I could find the correct one?

Comment: Oh the indicator doesn’t account for the negative parts. Perhaps I split the function into its positive and negative parts, find the corresponding indicator-function integrals of their graphs, and subtract them to obtain a value equal to the original multiple integral.

Comment: I have now edited the original post according to the details specified in my last comment.

Comment: The correct formula is that for $f \geq 0$, $\int_{X} f\,d\mu = (\mu \times m)(\{(x, y) \in X \times \mathbb{R} : 0 \leq y \leq f(x)\})$. This says that the integral of $f$ is the area under the graph of $f$.

Comment: @Kakashi I believe what I have is that generalized to arbitrary functions, which can be proven by splitting the integral up into positive and negative parts and applying your formula, like my formula is suggestively written. Unfortunately, I don’t see how to prove your formula.

Comment: @AbcedDecba Use Tonelli's theorem: $$\int_{X}f(x)\,d\mu(x) = \int_{X}\int_{0}^{f(x)}1\,dy\,d\mu(x) = \int_{X}\int_{\mathbb{R}}I(0 \leq y \leq f(x))\,dy\,d\mu(x) = (\mu \times m)(\{(x, y) \in X \times \mathbb{R} : 0 \leq y \leq f(x)\}).$$